# Why is JQuery Masonry not aligning vertically?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-masonry

I've been trying to set up the masonry grid for my WordPress theme. It doesn't align vertically. I've read many tutorials and searched many stackoverflow answers. I tried all of the solutions and nothing seems to work.

http://michellecantin.ca/test/portfolio-2/3444-2/

This is my CSS:

```
#container {
position:relative;
left:28%;
width:69%;
}

.item {
width:200px;
float:left;
background: #fff;
}
```

I have the JQuery functions in my head section:

```
<!--Jquery functions-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    // This block will be put in a separate file later on (JQuery.js)
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $container = $('#container');            
   //$container.imagesLoaded(function(){                    
      $container.masonry({
         itemSelector: '.item',
         isAnimated: true,
      });
   //});
});
</script>
```

After my header, I have the grid:

```
<div name="top" id="container">
    <div class="item">
        <h3>1</h3>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h3>2</h3>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h3>3</h3>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h3>4</h3>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h3>5</h3>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong! Please, I need your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some jQuery conflicts. This can happen because both you, Wordpress and your plugins are several loading pieces of jQuery code at several places. That needs some order to be able to work.

**You could try the following:**
Put all the bits of jQuery code in one file, for example here:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Put this in your footer, before the `</body>`

The jquery.js file and your masonry.jquery.js you have in your header are in the right place, so you can keep it there.

Now in your new script file, make sure your code is surround by **jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... });** , like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  //your masonry code goes here, f.e.:
  $('#container').masonry({ 
    isAnimated: true,
itemSelector: '.item'
   });

  //and your toggle function:
  $('.toggle-view-style1 li, .toggle-view-style2 li, .toggle-view-style3 li, .toggle-view-style4 li, .toggle-view-style5 li').click(function () {
    var text = $(this).children('div.panel');
    if (text.is(':hidden')) {
        text.slideDown('200');      
    } else {
        text.slideUp('200');    
    }

  });

  //and your close alert box
  $('.close-alert-box-style1, .close-alert-box-style2, .close-alert-box-style3, .close-alert-box-style4').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
  });

  // etc : so all the small pieces of jquery in your website, that now start with $(document).ready(function () { or jQuery(document).ready(function()              {

}); // end of jQuery ready function
```

If you manage to tidy up your code, it should work...